# Why didn't Asian countries expand and trade with Europe?

Tags: colonization

There are questions why China didn't explore and discover Europe.

The answer is that the Ming dynasty prohibits that. So the issue is that China is so centralized they can't do that. One king says no, then that's it.

However, Asia is not just China.

We got the Vietnamese, Japanese, Indonesians (with many maritime powers) and so on and so on.

Not one of them have good ship technology to travel to Europe?

Are the Chinese the only one with decent ship technology? The Chinese are not even a maritime nation.

Another explanation is the incentive. However, if Europeans want to trade with Asians, why Asians don't want to trade with Europeans?

Comment: A better question would be: "Why Western Europe expanded and started trade with all the rest of the world?"

Comment: What has your research shown you so far? Where have you already searched? Please help us to help you. Can you explain why the relevant Wikipedia pages and google searches didn't  answer the question?  [SE sites work best if the questions are supported by preliminary research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/2085030)

Comment: Mongols tried to take the place over. Ended up in semi-overloadship of Rus for a while, and of course you have the Tartars

Comment: My research suggests that the Chinese are the only one with good ship technology. I want to confirm that.

Comment: If European traders make big money going to Asia then Asia traders will also make big money going to Europe. Why don't they?

Comment: @user4951 - [Please don't reply in comments](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3915/1401), update the question.  The question would be stronger if it showed your prior research.

Comment: The Chinese didn't feel that Europe had anything worth getting.  Remember, the Europeans were driven by the desire to get cheaper access to commodities that came from Asia.  There was little or nothing Europeans made that Asians particularly wanted.

Comment: @StevenBurnap I know it is a usual proposition, but I do not think it believable; if the Asians did not want anything from Europe, then trade would not have happened at all. They did quite happily accept Europe's gold and silver.

Comment: @SJuan76: For a long time, gold and silver were the only thing the Chinese wanted... And then one day the Brits noticed that they loved opium.

Comment: they actually try to do it in early ming check zheng he https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zheng_He but before he reaches europe china fall to mongol

Comment: also indonesian native has reach madagascar at least according to their gene, and i assume why other asian except japan and china not trying to reach europe through sea due to they need to pass south africa sea (i dont know the english name) which is not stable full of storm and such as far as i know their boat also small not big ship unlike japan and china too and their wood is not suit for antartica or something like that.

Comment: One must consider that the only trade items from Western Europe desired by the Far East were silver and gold - which for centuries the European countries were more than pleased to undertake the full risk of transporting. Not until the Opium trade balloons does this change - by which time the European powers are much stronger and wealthier.

Comment: and industrialized clothes

Comment: i mean atlantic ocean not antartica, also i forgot is it mongol or manchuria that conquer china before Zheng He pullback from reaching europe or pass africa.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens  but wasn't search for gold the reason the Spanish later continue to explore and colonized Mexico?

Comment: @HaoSun: No - not until gold and silver were discovered in the New World. hHe original reason was to eliminate the Middle Eastern middlemen and get better prices for silk, spices, etc.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens  yes but once they knew the new world had gold and silver it was enough to motivate the Spanish to launch additional expeditions  My understanding is that at some point the expeditions were about gold and not spices which begs the question why wasn't  gold enough to motivate Asia?

Comment: @HaoSun because asia is rich with plenty natural resource they dont need anything other than exotic stuff (other than japan at least), and to many gold can make economy collapse i guess, silver actually more favorable in asia especially china, its the commoner money there, unlike europe at that time which in struggling from the silk road get cut by arabian kingdom. and as i mention Zheng He at least try to reach europe before europe even take voyage but they failed.

Comment: In the Book of the Later Han, it speaks of China importing coral, sea silk, cinnabar, and other things from the west.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Not one of them have good ship technology to travel to Europe?

At least as far as Japan is concerned, Japan sent 2 delegates.

1 [**Tenshō delegate**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensh%C5%8D_embassy)

Though, they ( meaning their ships and route are determined by the then Western people ), went to Europe as the first Japanese.

2 [**Tsunenaga Hasekura and the 1613 project**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasekura_Tsunenaga#The_1613_embassy_project)

> The shōgun had a new galleon built in Japan to bring Vizcaino back to New Spain, together with a Japanese embassy accompanied by Luis Sotelo. The galleon, named Date Maru by the Japanese and later San Juan Bautista by the Spanish, took 45 days work in building, with the participation of technical experts from the Bakufu (the Minister of the Navy Mukai Shōgen, an acquaintance of William Adams with whom he built several ships, dispatched his Chief Carpenter), 800 shipwrights, 700 smiths, and 3,000 carpenters. The daimyō of Sendai, Date Masamune, was put in charge of the project. He named one of his retainers, Hasekura Tsunenaga (his fief was rated at around 600 koku), to lead the mission:

It may be noteworthy that the lord, [**Masamune Date,**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_Masamune)  ( who actually commanded the building of this ship ) has a rumor that he had planned a coup to overthrow the Tokugawa Shogunate with the help of foreign power, especially that of Spanish Armada, whose loss to England was unknown to him.

So technically speaking, Japan sent its own missionary to Europe at least once with its own ship which they built by themselves.

Comment: I think the word you want is "ambassador" (or embassy, if you're talking about the mission.  In English, a "missionary" is someone who goes to a foreign country in order to try to spread their religion.

Comment: @jamesqf Jesuits were that kind of at the time in Japan.

Comment: Yes, the Jesuits went to Japan (and China & other Asian countries) as missionaries rather than ambassadors.  Their ultimate intent was to convert the "heathen" people of those countries to Christianity, rather than to establish trade or diplomatic relations.

Comment: interesting, then why didn't this become the main center of trade rather than Hong Kong

Comment: @HaoSun Can't you see the name of those who voted to close? The OP's question is too broad to answer. You don't know the silver-gold ration in Japan compared with that of European countries. Every country has each own unique factor. I can not simply cover them all.

Answer (score 8):

Trade wasn't done by a person in Vietnam walking to France to sell his goods. A chain of middlemen distributed the items across the "Silk Road". Tradewise, Europe and China knew about each other and didn't need to "discover" each other.

If you are asking why Asia didn't colonize anywhere else like Europe did:

China stopped focusing on sea based imperialism in the 15th century. They still engaged in land based imperialism and held influence in Korea, Malaya, and Indochina. Many Chinese merchants moved to Indochina, Indonesia, and Burma etc.

Japan became isolationist in the 17th century.

As for India, the Mughal empire did have land based imperialism but there aren't any small places they could colonize by sea.

Summary: Around 1700, The largest, most powerful countries focused on no colonialism, land based imperialism, or business influence. The smaller countries were too busy resisting the larger countries. If India wanted to, there was not much nearby to colonize by sea. Even the European powers only had a few forts and had a business relationship with existing powers.

Comment: But India did spread the Hindu religion (and Islam, later on) & some of its culture(s) to the islands of southeast Asia.

Comment: what was this "excellent gun" the Japanese had but banned.  I have never heard of this before.

Comment: I removed it. It was apocryphal.